# How to cover 2 images as backgroundimages on 2 sides

Tags: html, css

I just started with HTML and CSS and I'm trying to make a page that consists of 2 images, 1 image covers the whole left side and the other one covers the right side. Both of these images must be clickable and work on different resolutions.

I've tried making 1 image out of the 2 and using coordinates to make them clickable. I noticed that this doesn't work on different resolution so that didn't work. I also tried to make them cover the sides, but this too didn't work on different resolutions. I also can't use javascript for this, only HTML and CSS (school project).

This is 1 of the things I have tried:

```html
html {
  background-image: url(img1.png), url(img2.png);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: cover, cover;
}
```

expected result: 2 images, 1 to the left other one to the right, both covering the 2 sides

actual result: 2 images stacked on each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed as `background-size: 50% auto, 50% auto;`

```
                  for first image   for second image
background-size:  xSize ySize,      xSize ySize;
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1280/720), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/2080);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% auto, 50% auto;
}
```